# How do I create a page in SharePoint and manage its content?

Tags: api

I would like to set up a system for deploying content into a SharePoint (O365) site using C# code. I would be reading text files in Markdown format and either converting them into HTML for publishing, or relying on the SharePoint Markdown component to do the rendering.

I am aware of the PnP library, as well as the Microsoft Graph library, and the REST API, and several other libraries and techniques that could presumably be used, but I have not been able to locate any specific tutorials or documentation for creating pages in SharePoint.

I will readily admit to not being very familiar with SharePoint generally, and specifically I am completely unfamiliar with SharePoint development, so pointers to basic guides on the foundations would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very good handout for SharePoint can be found [here.](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3257924/sharepoint-online-cheat-sheet.html)

To use SharePoint with C#, you can find very useful guide by MSFT [here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Create a page with PnP PowerShell can be done [via this guide.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-modern-page-in-sharepoint-site-using-pnp-powershell)